# Prove $|A| \leq |B|$ for $1-1$ function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove $|A|\leq |B|$ if function $F:A\rightarrow B$ is a $1-1$ function.

I wanted to know how to prove this out of curiosity. The help is appreciated.

Comment: This will depend on how you define $\vert A \vert$. Also, are these sets finite or infinite?

Comment: That is the definition of $|A|\leq |B|$.

Comment: Sets are infinite...|A| and |B| stand for cardinality

Answer (score 1):

By definition a function ($F$) is called one-to-one (aka *injective*) if every element in the codomain ($B$) is mapped to by *at most* one element of the domain ($A$).

It follows immediately that the codomain must have at least as great a cardinality as the domain; $|A|\leqslant |B|$.   This holds whether the sets have finite or transfinite cardinality.

Comment: I have never personally seen a definition of $|A| \leq |B|$, that is not "there exists a one-to-one map from $A$ to $B$". Saying it "follows" confuses the issue to me.

Comment: @PVAl  Well, it is often defined that way *because* it follows, and it follows from, the existence of an injection.